# how to GET a partial value of a nested object in state for Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am writing unit tests for a class component in React. I want to test separate parts of one big object which takes up over 50 lines of code. While I can test the whole object as I change it line by line, I feel like my test will be near unreadable as I will be continually posting all 50 lines to test each single, nested value separately.

So after failing to figure out the syntax, I searched here and google and I see many q/a's on how to setState of a nested object but nothing on how to GET.

```
      // expect(component.state("addProjectForm['projectName']['value']")).toBe("")      
      // expect(component.state("addProjectForm")("projectName")("value")).toBe("")
      expect(component.state("addProjectForm")).toBe({"projectName": {"value" : ""}})
```

This is the setup for my test. They all fail, the last line does return the object and again, while I do know how to pass it, I will have to add another 54 lines of code and then repeat that for each of the 20+ unit tests I need to write for both the set up and then a second time after calling the inputChangeHandler() and I feel there must be a better way.

So... is it possible to only test the final layer of the object and if yes, how so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jest a `toMatchObject()` asserts "that a JavaScript object matches a subset of the properties of an object".

So the following will pass:

```
expect(component.state("addProjectForm")).toMatchObject({"projectName": {"value" : ""}})
```